# Buildozer error when compiling for Android: list index out of range

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I'm currently trying to compile a fairly simple Kivy app for use on Android. The application runs as intended, without errors or warnings, on desktop (linux and windows), however during compilation I run into the error given in the title. The following is a full copy of everything that is displayed during compilation:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/freakjoe/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/freakjoe/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/freakjoe/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Distribution already compiled, pass.
# Build the application #21
# Package the application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.33.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py2.7.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py2.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1020, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py2.7.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 91, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py2.7.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 103, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py2.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 211, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py2.7.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 645, in build_package
    self._update_libraries_references(dist_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py2.7.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 839, in _update_libraries_references
    if not content[-1].endswith(u'\n'):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have not made any changes to the .spec file created by running `buildozer init`. I'm using Python 2.7 and running Linux Mint.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the latest buildozer version? If not, it might be worth trying the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/BCz1cg_r9sw) Google Forum thread, your bug has been fixed and you should try updating your Buildozer installation.

> Mathieu Virbel:
>
> I recently fixed something about that, try master. If it doesn't work,
>   open an issue. If content[-1 doesn't work, it may mean that the
>   reference is empty, and so there is another issue somewhere before it.
>   Sending us the whole log may help.

Comment: Please checkout [Answering Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) format for your future answers at Stack overflow.Thank you.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan is this better? I edited the answer to include the quote.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error running:

```
buildozer android debug
```

I think the error appears after a <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd></kbd> press during a compilation in order to stop it. After that the error continues.

```
buildozer version == 0.35
python 3.6.6
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
```

In order to solve the error, I tried by using:

```
$ buildozer dist-clean
$ buildozer android clean
```

But the error persists.

So I recommend you to use `buildozer 0.34`

```
sudo -H pip3 install buildozer==0.34
```

If you are using python 2.7.x:

```
sudo -H pip install buildozer==0.34
```